# Inner function with "not enough values to unpack"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been stuck with an inner function tentative and after a lot of changes, I'm still seeing the same error at the end when I run it.

My function code is as below.

```
def test(name,df,col='',col2=''):  

    format_type = list(df[col]) 

    d = {name: pd.DataFrame() for name in format_type}     #create two sub_dataframe 


    for name, df, col2 in d.items():     #look at one sub_df at the time

        df['revenue_share']= (df[col2]/df[col2].sum())*100      #calculate revenue_share of each line

        print(df['revenue_share'])


        def function(df,col3='revenue_share'):      #function to separate the companies within several groups depending on their rev_share

            if (df[col3] < 0.5):
                return 'longtail'
            else:
                return df['company_name']

    df['company_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: function(x[col2],x),axis=1) .       #create a new column with the group name


    return df
```

and the error code when I run `test(print,format_company_df,col='format',col2='buyer_spend')`  :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-19c1a2b58a26> in <module>
----> 1 test(display,miq,col='format',col2='buyer_spend')
      2 

<ipython-input-41-5380164aff21> in test(name, df, col, col2)
      5     d = {name: pd.DataFrame() for name in format_type} #create two sub_dataframe - filtered by format (display or video)
      6 
----> 7     for name, df, col2 in d.items(): #look at display or video df
      8 
      9         df['revenue_share']= (df[col2]/df[col2].sum())*100   #calculate revenue_share of each line

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You probably just want: `for name, col2 in d.items():` as `df` is an existing parameter.

Comment: Why are you defining, but not calling, the function in the loop?

Comment: You've just filled ``d`` with a dict mapping each ``name`` to a ``df``. Why do you expect to get a ``name``, ``df`` **and** ``col2`` from it?

Comment: Why does your function take parameters for ``name`` and ``df``? These are never used but almost immediately overridden.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is a dictionary. `d.items()` yields the pair (key, value) at a time. So you can only assign them to 2 variables.

```
for name, df, col2 in d.items():
```

Here you are trying to assign them to 3 variables. And that's what the error is trying to say.

```
for df_name, sub_df in d.items():
```

This should work.

Nothing to do with inner functions.

Comment: The values are data frames, so it should probably be ``name, df`` instead.

Comment: Not clear from code what `col2` is supposed to be doing. However `df` is already a variable inside the method so don't think it should be getting used in that way.

Comment: ``name`` and ``col2 `` are also variables in the function.